# springboot won't generate classes from wsdl

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, wsdl

I tried a tutorial about consuming a SOAP web service via spring boot([GETTING STARTED - Consuming a SOAP web service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/)). But the classes are not generated when running the maven build. I'm totally new to this topic and need some help finding my mistake. Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.baumgarten</groupId>
<artifactId>springwsdlconsume</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- tag::wsdl[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>de.baumgarten.springwsdlconsume.hello.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>http://localhost:8080/ws/my_wsdl.wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::wsdl[] -->
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Maven build is successfull. It seems like the generate goal is never called. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Check the web-service URL `http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx?WSDL`. It doesn't exist. I'm hoping if you point to a web-service url that returns a WSDL, it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but as you can see, I have another url in my pom which points to an existing wsdl ;)

Comment: I tried with [this](http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl) web-service. And it worked.

Comment: Strange, still no class generation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try use the following plugin:-

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/wsdlFile.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I recommend also to have the following dependencies in your pom.xml:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove tag `pluginManagement`

It's used to fix a determined version of plugin.

Comment: Works fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in pom.xml. This will help you to generate java classes when you are using multiple wdsl. If you are using single WSDL then remove the last execution block from the below code.

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.14.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>number-conversion</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                        <generatePackage>com.walking.techie.number.conversion.wsdl</generatePackage>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                        <schemas>
                            <schema>
                                <url>http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso?WSDL</url>
                            </schema>
                        </schemas>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>commerce-service</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                        <generatePackage>com.walking.techie.wsdl</generatePackage>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                        <schemas>
                            <schema>
                                <url>http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl</url>
                            </schema>
                        </schemas>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    You can include the below maven dependency in the pom.xml file if you are using spring boot. It will provide WebServiceGatewaySupport class. You can extend this class in service layer and use getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive() method to call the wsdl service.
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.15.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-wsdl</arg> <!-- Enable WSDL support -->
                    </args>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>com.exmple.services.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```